# Override property definition in derived type in OpenAPI

Tags: swagger, openapi

dears,

In my OpenAPI schema, I have a base type `UserBase`, where the property `manager` is a string.

now I want to create a `RealUser` type derived from `UserBase` and want to override its property `manager` to be a custom type instead scalar.

```yaml
UserBase:
  title: User Base
  properties:
    name:
      description: User name
      type: string
    manager:
      description: Manager
      type: string

UserRef:
  title: UserRef
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      description: User ID
      type: string
      example: e58ed763-928c-4155-bee9-fdbaaadc15f3
    name:
      description: User name
      type: string
      example: Jon Snow

RealUser:
    title: Real User
    required:
      - name
    allOf:
      - $ref: #/components/schemas/UserBase
      - properties:
          manager:
            description: Reference to Manager
            allOf:
                - $ref: #/components/schemas/UserRef
```

**Swagger validator does not show any error**, however the [original documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/) says the following:

> It is recommended to avoid using conflicting properties (like properties that have the same names, but different data types)

So, my question - is it legal to do such override?

Any kind of clarification is appreciated!

Comment: Can you also post the `UserRef` schema? Whether or not your `RealUser` schema is valid depends on what `type` is used in `UserRef`.

Comment: hi @Helen, i've updated the initial request to include same